I use synchronous sleep and when I make sync requests the GUI freezes
this is my first python script and I don't quite understand. How can I use synchronous function calls but not freeze the graphics?
Please tell me.
If I use asynchronous sleep then cloud fire starts blocking my requests.
That's why I use synchronous sleep.
import logging
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import asyncio

from itertools import count
from time import sleep

import requests
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QTextCursor
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *                               # PyQt6
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt6.Qt6 import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from const import listGLNotUse, rep, forum_home_page_file, fileNameLog, data_folder_atricle, url_main, \
    fileName_last_filter_forum, file_name_forum_pages, dir_garbage, file_name_forum_page_torrent
from delelteTextBlock import deleteBlocks
from deleteDir import delete_file, deleteDirs
from main import replase_multiple, print_info, get_posts_forum_torrent, \
    get_torrent_Link, torrent_download, get_soup_text, request_cf


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def get_directory_and_linkFromFilteStr(self):

        soup = get_soup_text(forum_home_page_file)  #получить soup главной страницы
        line = re.split(';', self.filter)
        gr1 = line[0]
        gr2 = line[1]
        gr3 = line[2]

        skip_first_to = 'Трекер: Всё для детей и родителей'
        #
        is_skip_first_to = 1
        torrent_gr_list = []
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(data_folder_atricle):
                os.mkdir(data_folder_atricle)

            posts_table_forumling = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['forumlink', 'cattitle', 'gensmall tit-b']})

            adres_cattitle = ["cattitle"]  # 1
            adres_forumlink = ["forumlink"]  # 2
            adres_gensmall = ['gensmall', 'tit-b']  # 3

            count = 0
            is_row_gr_1_list = 0
            is_row_gr_2_list = 0
            is_row_gr_3_list = 0

            for item in posts_table_forumling:

                if item.text != skip_first_to.strip() and is_skip_first_to == 1:  # Удаляем мусор сначала
                    continue
                if item.text == skip_first_to.strip():
                    is_skip_first_to = 0

                if item.text not in listGLNotUse:  # Убираем группы где нет глав с торрентами
                    text_url = replase_multiple(item.get_text(), rep)

                    if text_url == "":  # Удаляем пустый урлы
                        # print('check blank continue', text_url)
                        continue

                    count += 1

                    # проверям есть ли текущая группа в фильтре для разрешения скачивания

                    if text_url == gr1:
                        is_row_gr_1_list = 1
                    else:
                        is_row_gr_1_list = 0

                    if text_url == gr2:
                        is_row_gr_2_list = 1
                    else:
                        is_row_gr_2_list = 0

                    if text_url == gr3:
                        is_row_gr_3_list = 1
                    else:
                        is_row_gr_3_list = 0

                    if item.get(
                            "class") == adres_cattitle and is_row_gr_1_list == 1:  # работа с рутовыми главами. Уровень глобальный
                        name1 = "value1: ", item.get("class"), {count}, text_url, item.get("href")
                        print_info(f'1-filter: {text_url}-{name1}')
                        directory_root = f'{data_folder_atricle}''/'f'{text_url}'

                        if not os.path.exists(directory_root):
                            os.mkdir(directory_root)

                    if item.get(
                            "class") == adres_forumlink and is_row_gr_2_list == 1:  # работа с группами главам. Уровень 2
                        name2 = "value2: ", item.get("class"), {count}, text_url, item.get("href")
                        print_info(f'2-filter: {text_url}-{name2}')
                        name_directory2 = directory_root + "/" + text_url

                        # print(name_directory2)

                        if not os.path.exists(name_directory2):
                            os.mkdir(name_directory2)
                        #
                    if item.get("class") == adres_gensmall and is_row_gr_3_list == 1:  # работа с темами.Уровень 3
                        name3 = "value3: ", item.get("class"), {count}, text_url, item.get("href")
                        print_info(f'3-filter: {text_url}-{name3}')
                        name_directory3 = name_directory2 + "/" + text_url

                        torrent_gr_dc = {
                            'dir': name_directory3
                            , 'url': url_main + item.get("href")
                            , 'name': text_url
                        }

                        torrent_gr_list.append(torrent_gr_dc)

                        if not os.path.exists(name_directory3):
                            os.mkdir(name_directory3)
                            # print(item.get("class"))

            self.list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory = torrent_gr_list

            if (len(torrent_gr_list) > 0):
                with open(fileName_last_filter_forum, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
                    for line in torrent_gr_list:
                        file.write(f"{line}\n")

            return torrent_gr_list
        except Exception as ex:
            print_info('1: ', ex)

    def get_posts_forum_torrent(self):
        list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory = self.list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory
        print('1111')
        print(list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory)
        # 1- скачать файлы страниц с торрентами
        # 0- не скачивать
        try:
            is_create_file = 1
            # скачиваются только 1 страницы с постами где есть торренты. пример https://nnmclub.to/forum/viewforum.php?f=731&start=1400#pagestart

            if not os.path.exists(dir_garbage):
                os.mkdir(dir_garbage)

            count_page_first_group4 = 0
            post_topis_list = []
            post_1_page_list = []

            for itemGroup in list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory:
                url = itemGroup.get('url')
                # анализиуются первый страницы всех глав.  Если указать лимит то будет анализироваться только часть
                # if count_page_first_group4 >= 5: #лимит на закачку топиков  всех первых страниц и торрентов и нет
                #     # (в некоторых затем будут лежать топикы с торрент файлами)
                #     break
                #
                # посмотреть по логам куда и зачем идут запросы.
                # может их все сохранить в файл.
                # потом ребята могут сами пробежаться по этим файлам и скачать себе торренты и не запариваться со cf
                request_posts_with_torrents = request_cf(url, False)
                count_page_first_group4 += 1

                namefile = itemGroup.get('name')
                item_text = request_posts_with_torrents.content.decode('cp1251')  #

                sleep_second = random.randrange(0, 1)  # 5-15
                print_info(f'Надо подождать. Смена page. Жду:{sleep_second}')
                sleep(sleep_second)

                text_clear = deleteBlocks(item_text, 'script')
                post_clear_utf = deleteBlocks(text_clear, 'meta').encode()
                #
                if request_posts_with_torrents.status_code != 200:
                    print('Попробуйте помеенять VPN. Сервер вернул не 200: ' + str(
                        request_posts_with_torrents.status_code))

                soup = get_soup_text(post_clear_utf)
                # анализирую первую страницы - если есть посты с торрентами то сохраню их для дальнейшего получения страниц по данной группе с торрентами
                topic_soup = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['topictitle']})
                #

                if topic_soup == []:
                    # print(itemGroup, ' тут нет списка торрент-постов: ',topic_soup)
                    continue
                #
                if topic_soup != []:  # есть посты-топики для торрентов
                    if is_create_file == 1:
                        namefile_temp1 = f'{dir_garbage}/{count_page_first_group4}' f'{namefile}.html'

                        with open(namefile_temp1, 'wb') as file:
                            print_info(
                                f'Тут есть торренты, поэтому ее сохраняю: {namefile_temp1}-{count_page_first_group4}')
                            file.write(post_clear_utf)

                    topic_soup_pages_list = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('pagestart'))  # .find_-.find_all('span')
                    # print('size: ', len(topic_soup_pages_list))
                    # print(topic_soup_pages_list)
                    post_page_list_temp = []  # для очистки Page от След
                    is_page = len(topic_soup_pages_list)
                    # for item_topik_first_page in topic_soup_pages_list:
                    #     print(item_topik_first_page)
                    if is_page > 0:
                        for item in topic_soup_pages_list:
                            url_href = item.get('href')
                            url_text = item.getText()

                            if url_text != "След.":
                                number = int(item.text.strip())
                                post_page_list_temp.append(number)
                                # print('t1: ', url_href, 't2:', url_text, 'item:',item.text)

                        # print_list(post_page_list_temp)
                        max_page = max(post_page_list_temp)
                        # print('max: 'f'{maxPage}')
                        count_for = max_page * 50

                        # Проверить что будет делать есть только 1 страницы с торрентами

                        # формирование только урлов на страницы всех pages
                        for i in range(0, count_for, 50):
                            if i == 0:
                                url_first = itemGroup.get('url')
                                # print(url_first)

                                post_topic_dc = {
                                    'dir': itemGroup.get('dir')
                                    , 'url_topic_group': itemGroup.get('url')
                                    , 'url_topic': url_first
                                    , 'i': i
                                }

                                post_topis_list.append(post_topic_dc)
                                continue

                            # print(i)
                            url_two_and_other = url_href.rsplit('&', 1)[0]
                            url = f'{url_main}{url_two_and_other}&start={i}#pagestart'
                            # rint(url)
                            post_topic_dc = {
                                'dir': itemGroup.get('dir')
                                , 'url_topic_group': itemGroup.get('url')
                                , 'url_topic': url
                                , 'i': i
                            }
                            post_topis_list.append(post_topic_dc)
                    # если страница с только с 1 page пример https://nnmclub.to/forum/viewforum.php?f=736 на 07.09.2024. 08:37:27
                    if is_page == 0:
                        post_topic_dc = {
                            'dir': itemGroup.get('dir')
                            , 'url_topic_group': itemGroup.get('url')
                            , 'url_topic': url
                            , 'i': 0
                        }
                        post_topis_list.append(post_topic_dc)

            self.pages_torrents_link = post_topis_list
            with open(file_name_forum_pages, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
                for line in post_topis_list:
                    file.write(f"{line}\n")

            return post_topis_list
        except Exception as ex:
            print_info('2: ', ex)

    def get_torrent_Link(self):
        pages_torrents_link = self.pages_torrents_link

        # 1- скачать файлы страниц с торрентами
        # 0- не скачивать
        # for item in pages_torrents_link:
        #     print_info("get_torrent_Link. list:", item)

        # скачиваются все страницы с пейджами 1 страницы с постами где есть торренты. пример https://nnmclub.to/forum/viewforum.php?f=731&start=1400#pagestart
        if not os.path.exists(dir_garbage):
            os.mkdir(dir_garbage)

        try:
            post_topis_download_torrent_list = []
            post_url_torrent = []
            count = 0
            len_gtl = len(pages_torrents_link)

            if len_gtl == 0:
                print_info('Торренты в этой группе не найдены...')
            else:
                print_info(f'Страниц с торрентами: {len_gtl}-{pages_torrents_link}')

            for itemGlobalDir in pages_torrents_link:
                count += 1
                count_random = 1  # random.randrange(1, 3)

                # print('Сколько страниц с торрентами анализировать 'f'{count_random}')

                # if count > count_random: # лимит запрос получения страниц с файлом торрентов
                #    break

                # страница типа https://nnmclub.to/forum/viewforum.php?f=725 может быть и любая из page
                requests_torrent_topik = request_cf(itemGlobalDir.get('url_topic'), False)

                sleep_second = random.randrange(3, 10)
                print_info(f'Надо подождать. Получаю ссылку на страницу torrent файлом. Жду:{sleep_second}')
                sleep(sleep_second)

                item_text = requests_torrent_topik.content.decode('cp1251')  #
                text_clear = deleteBlocks(item_text, 'script')
                post_clear_utf = deleteBlocks(text_clear, 'meta').encode()

                soup_pages_torrent = get_soup_text(post_clear_utf)

                topic_soup = soup_pages_torrent.find_all('a', {'class': ['topictitle']})

                # определяется имя поста где лежит торрент и урл на страницу с торрентом
                count_page_torrent_get = 0
                # print_info(f'itemGlobalDir: {itemGlobalDir}')

                for item_post_url_name in topic_soup:
                    count_page_torrent_get += 1
                    len_ptsl = len(pages_torrents_link)
                    print_info(f'Page c torrents : {count} из {len_ptsl}')
                    print_info(f'Анализ торрентов на page: {item_post_url_name} itemGlobalDir:{itemGlobalDir}')
                    len_tps = len(topic_soup)
                    print_info(f'Анализ торрент файлов на page: {count_page_torrent_get} из {len_tps}')

                    # сколько страниц с торрентами получать для сохранения
                    # if count_page_torrent_get >=3:
                    #     break

                    name_file = item_post_url_name.text
                    url = url_main + item_post_url_name.get('href')
                    print_info(f'{name_file}-{url}')

                    sleep_second = random.randrange(1, 10)
                    print_info(f'Получаю ссылку на download файла.torrent. Жду:{sleep_second}')
                    sleep(sleep_second)

                    request_posts_with_torrents = request_cf(url, False)
                    item_text_page_torrent = request_posts_with_torrents.content.decode('cp1251')  #
                    text_clear_with_torrents = deleteBlocks(item_text_page_torrent, 'script')
                    post_clear_with_torrents_utf = deleteBlocks(text_clear_with_torrents, 'meta').encode()
                    # example post_clear_with_torrents_utf https://nnmclub.to/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1458717

                    soup_torrent_page = get_soup_text(post_clear_with_torrents_utf)
                    topic_soup_download = soup_torrent_page.find_all(href=re.compile('download.php'))

                    len_dw_torrent = len(topic_soup_download)
                    print_info(f'Найдено на торрент страница ссылок на скачку: {len_dw_torrent}')
                    if len_dw_torrent < 1:
                        break

                    url_torrent = url_main + topic_soup_download[0].get('href')

                    post_download_torrent_list_dc = {
                        'dir': itemGlobalDir.get('dir')
                        , 'name_topic': name_file + "_" + str(random.randrange(1, 9999999))
                        , 'url_torrentDownloader': url_torrent
                    }
                    post_url_torrent.append(url_torrent)
                    post_topis_download_torrent_list.append(post_download_torrent_list_dc)

            for item in post_topis_download_torrent_list:
                print_info(f'{item}')

            if (len(post_topis_download_torrent_list) > 0):
                with open(file_name_forum_page_torrent, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
                    print_info(f'Промежуточное сохранение get_torrent_Link. ссылка на фай торрент + место хранения')
                    for line in post_topis_download_torrent_list:
                        file.write(f"{line}\n")

            if (len(post_url_torrent) > 0):
                with open("ALL_post_url_torrent.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
                    print_info(f'Сохраняю урл на скачку торрента файла в post_url_torrent')
                    for line in post_url_torrent:
                        file.write(f"{line}\n")

            return post_topis_download_torrent_list
        except Exception as ex:
            print_info('3: ', ex)

    # def torrent_download(torrent_link):
    #     count = 0
    #     try:
    #         if torrent_link is not None:
    #             size_list_toreent_file = len(torrent_link)
    #
    #         for item in torrent_link:
    #             count += 1
    #             if torrent_link is None:
    #                 continue
    #             sleep_second = random.randrange(3, 10)
    #             print_info(f'Перед скачкой torrent файла. Жду:{sleep_second}')
    #             sleep(sleep_second)
    #
    #             url_torrentDownloader = item.get('url_torrentDownloader')
    #             dir = item.get('dir')
    #             print_info(f'{url_torrentDownloader} сюда{dir}')
    #             url = item.get('url_torrentDownloader')
    #             filename = replase_multiple(item.get('name_topic'), rep) + ".torrent"
    #             directory = item.get('dir')
    #             # urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
    #
    #             try:
    #
    #                 print_info(f'Сохранение файла torrent: {count} из {size_list_toreent_file}')
    #                 self.download(url, directory, filename)
    #             except Exception as _ex:
    #                 print('4: ', _ex)
    #
    #         link_down = len(torrent_link)
    #         print_info(f'Скачено торрентов: {link_down}')
    #
    #     except Exception as _ex2:
    #         print_info('5: ', _ex2)

    # def download(url: str, dest_folder: str, name_file: str):
    #     try:
    #         file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, name_file)
    #         print_info(f'dest_folder: {dest_folder}')
    #         print_info(f'name_file: {name_file}')
    #         print_info(f'url: {url}')
    #
    #         r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    #         if r.ok:
    #             path_info = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    #             print_info(f'saving to: {path_info}')
    #
    #             with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    #                 for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
    #                     if chunk:
    #                         f.write(chunk)
    #                         f.flush()
    #                         os.fsync(f.fileno())
    #             time.sleep(3)  # одождать 3 секунды
    #         else:  # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
    #             print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
    #     except Exception as _ex:
    #         with open("torrent_downloadError.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf8') as file:
    #             print_info(f'Промежуточное сохранение файлов торрентов которые не скачались. torrent_downloadError')
    #             file.write(f"{url};{dest_folder};{name_file}\n")
    #         print_info('6: ', _ex)



    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.soup = [{1},{2},{3}]
        self.set_appear()
        self.init_ui()
        self.connections()


    def set_appear(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Парсер nnmclub")
        self.resize(1200, 600)

    def connections(self):
        self.start_task_button.clicked.connect(self.start_task)
    def start_task(self):
        for ix in self.task_tree.selectedIndexes():
          text = ix.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
          # or ix.data()
        self.filter = text

        if text != "Выберите раздел" :
            str = f'Выбран раздел: {text}'
            self.log_text_edit.append(str)
            logging.info(str)
        try:
            worker = Worker(
                parserFunction(self)
            )
            self.thread_pool.start(worker)
        except:
            self.log_text_edit.append(f"Произошла ошибка во время парсинга , проверьте правильность ввода данных.")


    def init_ui(self):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=fileNameLog, encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)  # включаем логирование

        self.thread_pool = QThreadPool()
        # Создание виджета вкладок
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()

        # Создание вкладки "Группы"
        self.tasks_tab = QWidget()
        self.tasks_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tasks_tab.setLayout(self.tasks_layout)

        # Создание "Иерархии групп" на вкладке "Группы"
        self.task_tree = QTableWidget()
        self.task_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.task_tree.header().hide()
        self.task_tree.resize(1000, 450)

        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, 'Выберите раздел')

        soup = get_soup_text(forum_home_page_file)
        list = get_forum_global_page(soup)

        for itemlistPost in list:
            self.task_tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
            q = QTreeWidgetItem(item)
            # name = 'itemlistPost'
            name = itemlistPost.get('name1') +";"+ itemlistPost.get('name2')+";"+ itemlistPost.get('name3')
            q.setText(0, name)


        # Установка стилей для Иерархии групп и кнопки
        self.tasks_layout.addWidget(self.task_tree)
        self.log_text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.log_text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
        # self.log_text_edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.tasks_layout.addWidget(self.log_text_edit)

        # Создание кнопки "Начать загрузку"
        self.start_task_button = QPushButton("Начать загрузку")
        # self.del_task_button.setStyleSheet(self.del_btn_style)

        self.buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.start_task_button)
        self.tasks_layout.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)

        # Добавление вкладки "Группы" в виджет вкладок
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tasks_tab, "Группы")

        # Создание вкладки "Настройки"
        settings_tab = QWidget()
        settings_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()

        # Добавление настроек
        # Поле для выбора папки по умолчанию
        folder_label = QLabel("Папка по умолчанию:")
        self.folder_button = QPushButton("Выбрать папку")

        form_layout.addRow(self.folder_button)

        # settings_layout.addWidget(self.auto_start_checkbox_default)
        settings_layout.addLayout(form_layout)

        settings_tab.setLayout(settings_layout)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(settings_tab, "Настройки")

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

  

def panelCreate(soup):

    app = QApplication([])
    app.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
    aw = MainWindow()
    aw.show()
    app.exec()
    # sys.exit(app.exec())


def parserFunction(self):
    self.log_text_edit.append(f'parserFunction')

    # получить фильтр
    list_gr1_gr2_gr3_url_directory = self.get_directory_and_linkFromFilteStr()
    print('000')
    post_genmed_list = self.get_posts_forum_torrent()
    #
    post_download_link = get_torrent_Link(post_genmed_list)
    # print(post_download_link)

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            asyncio.run(self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


def get_forum_global_page(soup):
    skip_first_to = 'Трекер: Всё для детей и родителей'

    is_skip_first_to = 1
    torrent_gr_list = []
    try:
        posts_table_forumling = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['forumlink', 'cattitle', 'gensmall tit-b']})

        adres_cattitle = ["cattitle"]  # 1
        adres_forumlink = ["forumlink"]  # 2
        adres_gensmall = ['gensmall', 'tit-b']  # 3

        count = 0

        for item in posts_table_forumling:

            if item.text != skip_first_to.strip() and is_skip_first_to == 1:  # Удаляем мусор сначала
                continue
            if item.text == skip_first_to.strip():
                is_skip_first_to = 0

            if item.text not in listGLNotUse:  # Убираем группы где нет глав с торрентами
                text_url = replase_multiple(item.get_text(), rep)

                if text_url == "":  # Удаляем пустый урлы
                    # print('check blank continue', text_url)
                    continue

                count += 1
                if item.get("class") == adres_cattitle:  # работа с рутовыми главами. Уровень глобальный
                    name1 = text_url
                if item.get("class") == adres_forumlink:  # работа с группами главам. Уровень 2
                    name2 = text_url
                if item.get("class") == adres_gensmall:  # работа с темами.Уровень 3
                    torrent_gr_dc = {
                        'name1': name1
                        , 'name2': name2
                        , 'name3': text_url
                    }

                    torrent_gr_list.append(torrent_gr_dc)

        return torrent_gr_list
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)








I used asynchronous sleep. I expected that the graphic panel would not freeze. But the problems were added by cloudfire.

I first write a console application, but I want to ask the guys who support the site to make a graphical application. I thought maybe the functions should be exactly like class methods. (then the worker thread) but the miracle did not happen

I tried to create a stream in a separate method, but I couldn’t pass my request functions with parameters there...And nothing worked either.



can you set a tımer that expıres after the specıfıed duratıon to resume executıon or rather regıster a call cack functıon that wıll be executed when sleep ıs completed

It is necessary to create a class inheriting from Qthread.
class RequestThread(QThread):
def __init__(self, mainwindow, parent=None):
    super().__init__()
    # print('created qthread')
    # self.mainwindow = mainwindow

def run(self):
    value = self.mainwindow.number1
    this insert request  function

    while value < 100:
        time.sleep(0.1)

        value = value + 1
        self.mainwindow.log_text_edit.append(f'1111')

in constructor add
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RequestThread_instance = RequestThread(mainwindow=self)

add handler click button:
 def connections(self):
        self.start_task_button.clicked.connect(self.start_task)

    def start_task(self):
        print('start_task')
        self.RequestThread_instance.start()

